# Имитация зажатия клавиш в Android

Tags: java, android

Как можно имитировать зажатие клавиши **D** с помощью java-кода в Android среде?
Я слышал об инструментах, но так я могу только нажать клавишу D:

```
Instrumentation instr = new Instrumentation();
instr.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам для тестов или просто так?

Comment: Мне требуется для, тестов

Comment: Возможно здесь найдете нужный вам ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24482403/5479247

Comment: Помогло, больше спасибо! То, что искал